# How do I create an instance of IPortableDeviceManager in python?

Tags: python, com

I'm trying to import photos from portable device (iphone, Android) using Windows Portable Device API which is exposed via COM. I saw some code that did using c# like following after adding the reference of PortableDeviceApiLib.dll:

```
PortableDeviceApiLib.PortableDeviceManagerClass devMgr = new PortableDeviceApiLib.PortableDeviceManagerClass();
```

What would be the way to do same inside python?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able by doing the following:

```
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
CreateObject("{0af10cec-2ecd-4b92-9581-34f6ae0637f3}")
```

However, you should then cast it (`QueryInterface`) to something useful:

```
import os
from comtypes.client import GetModule
GetModule(os.getenv("WINDIR") + "\\system32\\PortableDeviceApi.dll")
from comtypes.gen.PortableDeviceApiLib import *
CreateObject(PortableManager)
```

`CreateObject` will inspect the first argument to see if it is an object with a `_reg_clsid_` attribute, a `comtypes.GUID` instance, a CLSID string (i.e. starts with `{`) and finally tries to lookup the CLSID assuming it's a ProgID.

It will also inspect the first argument for a `_com_interfaces_` attribute, which is supposed to be a list of interfaces, and fetch the first one as the default interface to `QueryInterface` for, if the `interface` argument is not provided.